# Salesforce Bulk API v2 retries

Tags: salesforce, ingest

I have an ingest job which takes a long time to process (in bulk api v2). I suspect, due to the multiple retries.

Can someone please help me understand if I can use Sforce-Disable-Batch-Retry to disable retries in bulk api v2?

Thank you!

I saw that Sforce-Disable-Batch-Retry is available in bulk api, but couldn't find anything about bulk api v2